# aligning a text box in html

Tags: html, css

How to align a text box, left or right of the HTML page?

We all know how to align a picture to the right. But how do I create a textbox (with a border and a different background color) and how do I integrate this textbox into a paragraph so that the body text skirts the textbox with a specific padding?

Comment: Please read [ask], noting that you are supposed to do some _research_ before asking a question.  Then if you'd like to still ask the question, please provide an [mcve] showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

> We all know how to align a picture to the right.

The above is a little presumptuous.

I'd agree that your question needs examples of what you've tried. It also needs clarity around what you are asking for. I'm assuming that the code below is what you are after.

This example uses floats which will cause the wrapping effect that you mention, however for layout similar to this, I would take a good look at [CSS Grid](https://cssgrid.io/).

```css
section {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

#funky {
  background: pink;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border: 3px dashed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p id="main">
    <div id="funky">
      Aliquam erat volutpat. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer
    </div>
    Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Sed in libero ut nibh placerat accumsan. jfdkjfd fdsjlfdsj Aliquam lobortis. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Vivamus euismod mauris. Vivamus euismod mauris. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vivamus euismod mauris. Vivamus euismod mauris. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vivamus euismod mauris. Vivamus euismod mauris. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Proin pretium, leo ac pellentesque mollis, felis nunc ultrices eros, sed gravida augue augue mollis justo. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi.
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` and assign `float: left` or `right` to it (same as with floated images), plus a width setting to not have it span the whole page (percentage or px)

Comment: Sorry for a badly formulated question. I did as you advised with div and float and it worked! Thank you very much.